# Sed Regexp Command not working

Tags: ubuntu, sed, regular-expression

So i have a line in a file that looks like this:

```
#multiline.pattern: ^\[
```

and im trying to use sed to replace it with this:

```
multiline.pattern: '^\['
```

and the command im using to do this is:

```
sudo sed -i 's/multiline.pattern: \^\\\[/multiline.pattern: '\'\^\\\\[\'/g' /etc/filename.txt
```

but everytime i do run this command i get this:

[image]

can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. If at all possible, please avoid attaching screenshots of console output; copy-and-paste the output with code formatting instead, as screenshots are often difficult to read and contributors trying to investigate have to type-copy the text.

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, something like this should work:

```
$ cat ex
#multiline.pattern: ^\[

$ sed -e "s/^#multiline\.pattern:.*/multiline.pattern: '^\\\['/" ex
multiline.pattern: '^\['
```

That replaces a line that starts with `#multiline.pattern:` followed by any number of characters to the end of the line with the pattern you're after.

The pattern you're after includes some special symbols (`\`, `[`), which I escaped with an additional `\` (e.g., `\\` gets you a literal `\`, 
`\[` gets you a literal `[`).

Answer (score 0):

you might work around that : `sed "s@\^@\'\^@;s/$/\'/"`

```
$ cat > toto
#multiline.pattern: ^\[
$ sed "s@\^@\'\^@;s/$/\'/" toto
#multiline.pattern: '^\['
```

Idea is to substitude `^` by `'^` and then end of line by `'` with end of line
in two consecutive actions to simplify the regexp.

of course with `sed -i ...` it modifies the file

Answer (score 0):

Where it's going wrong is the way the last part is [quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html):

```bsh
sed 's/multiline.pattern: \^\\\[/multiline.pattern: '\'\^\\\\[\'/g'
  # ^                                               ^             ^ ?
```

That last part is `backslash` escaped until the end where another single quote was *opened*. That's why `bash` gave the `$PS2` prompt `>`, allowing you to type in more stuff until the quote is closed with another `'`

Remove that last `'` and it will work:

```bsh
sed 's/multiline.pattern: \^\\\[/multiline.pattern: '\'\^\\\\[\'/g
# or:
sed 's/multiline.pattern: ^\\\[/multiline.pattern: '"'^\\\['/g"
sed "s/multiline.pattern: ^\\\\\[/multiline.pattern: '^\\\['/g"
sed 's/multiline.pattern: ^\\\[/multiline.pattern: \x27^\\[\x27/g'
```

---

Also:

- From your example output, it seems that you want to remove the `#` as well. To do so, include it in the matching pattern for `sed` (using whichever quoting style you prefer):

```bsh
sed 's/#multiline...'
```

- It's possible to use brackets to "catch" parts of your matching pattern, so that you can reuse those parts in the substitution (called [subexpressions & back-references](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions)):

```bsh
sed -r 's/#(multiline\.pattern: )(\^\\\[)/\1'\'\\2\'/g
```

(using `-r` / `--regexp-extended` isn't necessary for that, but it's more readable)

- It's best to check that your `sed` command is functioning as intended by first running it without the `-i` / `--in-place` option so the output can be checked for errors, instead of overwriting the file with potential errors.